# What do I need to study discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I think I should have some mathematical background to study discrete mathematics, so I am planning to read *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* by Susanna S. Epp.

Is there something I should study before starting this course?

Comment: I recommend starting to read it. You'll quickly discover whether there are things you don't know but need to. Then you can ask here about how to learn those. (PS I think it's a good book.)

Comment: You may want to read David Makinson's [Sets, Logic and Maths for Computing](https://books.google.com/books?id=zz9wDBjsqlAC) before diving any deeper.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, you are right.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, i take a look into the book i think it's very similar to the book i will read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete Mathematics is quite basic part of mathematics, there are no real prerequisite to that (other than general familiarity with mathematics and basic proofwriting). However you should pay attention to whether the book is an introductory book or advanced book.

For this particular book you can see more than the preface on Amazon. Especially you can see the first chapters and get some idea of the level. To me it looks like she begins from the basic.

Sure some good knowledge in algebra wouldn't hurt, but to me it looks to start at the same level as introductory university course in algebra here. What they call different stages of education where you live I can't tell, but generally I'd say completed "math oriented" education for 18-20 years old students should suffice.

Comment: THANKS, How i can know it's an introductory or advanced one ? I just read on the preface of the book, that's it's recommended to have a good background with algebra.

Comment: @android What I see on Amazon it seems like the algebra background is not that much of a requirement, at least not university algebra.

Comment: That's right, i'v started it, and i\m enjoying it.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt Discrete Mathematics is a basic part of mathematics, it requires basic knowledge of maths. There are many application of Discrete Mathematics in logic building in programming as well. Most of the artificial intelligent program are based with the logic of Discrete Mathematics. I'd like to recommend you this book as well "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications by Kenneth H. Rosen 7th Ed"
Do try solving exercises as it will help you understanding topics well.